# How to read table relationships?

Tags: sql, database

Lets say I have a Customer table and a Transaction Table, and I say that the Customer to Transaction relationship is One to Many.

So we can say "One Customer has Many Transactions"...

**Here is my first question:**

But is it true when I say...

"Many Transactions have One Customer"?

**Here is my second question:**

Does it have to be true both ways in order to establish a relationship in a given domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relationship is bi-directional, though the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29) in each direction does not have to be identical.

In your example it is indeed correct to say "One Customer has Many Transactions".

But "Many Transactions have One Customer" is not entirely accurate. You can say "Each transaction has exactly one customer" (assuming a transaction *must* have a customer), you can add, after this "Many transactions can belong to one customer", but both statements need to be present in order to be accurate.

---

Both sets of statements need to be true in order for a relationship to be fully described.

Comment: Is this true for Many to Many relationships as well?

Comment: @fullNelson - As you can figure out, in a many to many relationship, you don't have the "exactly one" constraint (as that would exclude one side from the many cardinality).

Comment: I think I am also getting hung up on semantics. Where I think I am having problem is selecting a domain, any domain, and having to consider everything about that domain in order to establish a relationship. If I choose Customers and Credit cards I have to dig down into details such as: Can a single credit card have more than one Customer associated with it? This is possible. So do I choose a Many to Many relationship? I think its that granular nature that can confuse me.

Comment: @fullNelson - If the domain says that each customer can hold several cards and that each card can be held by several customers, then yes, this is modeled as a many to many relationship.

Comment: Your last statement about customer and cards really simplifies it. It become more clear when you talk about relationships possessively. Thank you.

Comment: If we agree to say, *‘Many transactions **can** belong to one customer’*, it should also be more accurate to say, *‘One Customer **can have*** (rather than *has*) *Many Transactions’*.

Answer (score 1):

A one-to-many relationship is the most common type of relationship. In this type of relationship, a row in table A can have many matching rows in table B, but a row in table B can have only one matching row in table A. For example, the publishers and titles tables have a one-to-many relationship: each publisher produces many titles, but each title comes from only one publisher.

Make a one-to-many relationship if only one of the related columns is a primary key or has a unique constraint.

The primary key side of a one-to-many relationship is denoted by a key symbol. The foreign key side of a relationship is denoted by an infinity symbol.

This is a direct quote from

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s9x13w7.aspx)

Edit:

What you're describing, if "one transaction has multiple customers" -AND- "customers have multiple  transactions"

is a many to many relationship

Answer (score 1):

Talking about SQL generically, I don't know that "Have"/"has" is useful or standard or common terminology.  I'd say "is associated with" or "has a corresponding".

Anyway if it's one to many it'd be more accurate to say "All transactions have one customer", unless there can be transactions with no associated customer, in which case you would says "transactoions have zero or one customer"

SQL doesn't support many-to-many per se, usually you have a "link table" or "association table" so for example if one transaction can be associated with multiple customers (say people can do a group purchase) you could have a table called CustomerTransactionAssociation that has two fields: CustomerID and TransactionID.  Customer and Transaction don't have any foreign keys (that is, you can't look at just a customer record and see what it's associated with or if it's associated with anything).

Is there any particular platform or thing you're trying to get done?

Comment: It does seem I am limiting my thought process by sticking to "have" and "has". That really puts a bottle neck on what I think I am trying to get at.

Comment: To answer your question, I am trying to establish a relationship between a player table, an inventory, and the items a player puts in that inventory.